# Thickbox Close button increase after every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, thickbox

I use Thickbox  for my website, when I use this code Thickbox close button repeat and increase
I use following code to call Thickbox.

```
<div class="btnone2"><a href="signin.htm?placeValuesBeforeTB_=savedValues&TB_iframe=true&height=560&width=470 allowtransparency=true" class="thickbox req" >Already a client? Sign In</a></div>
```

[image]

and when I press again

[image]

and again and again it 'll increase number of close button

Comment: Waht you have tried? Can you Show you code?

Comment: I'm gonna open page vai iframe in thickbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thickbox.js and thickbox.css are included twice in page. That's why my problem occurred. I Remove this duplication and your problem will solved.